# SimpleForm: inherit wrappers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inheritance, simple-form

I use a default wrapper for most of my input fields. For a few though, I need a wrapper that is a very little bit different, which means that it only adds a class "inline" to the outer most wrapper tag.

Is there a way to inherit wrappers? Otherwise I have to copy&paste the wrappers, and have to maintain them both when changing something that both rely on.